# Insert Data Into Database Using Ajax - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database

I have page with a form and when user submit form , two things going to happend 
1) It should send an email (this part working fine) and 
2) It should also insert Data/record into Database, but this part not working and it cant insert data into database.
3) As i understand both Controller & AJAX working until its come to sending Email. not anymore.

> The things i tried for part 2 ,first  i debugged my
>   controller and i can see model contains the data.
>  I also check the
>   Console in browser and there was no errors

Did i miss something in Controller or in AJAX ?! 
Can anyone point me in the right direction ?!

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(string kundenavn, string ordrenummer , string send)
        {


            if (send == "send")
            {
                var SubjectOne = "RMAAJAX";
                var SendToPrint = "someemal@email.com";
                var errorMessage = "";


            try
            {
                // Initialize WebMail helper
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
                WebMail.UserName = "someemal@email.com";
                WebMail.Password = "";
                WebMail.From = "someemal@email.com";
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
                WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = false;


                // Send email
                WebMail.Send(to: SendToPrint,
                    subject: SubjectOne,
                    body: "Kundenavn" + kundenavn + "<br>" + "ordernummer" + ordrenummer + "<br>"

                    );

            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                errorMessage = ex.Message;

           }



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.RMA_History.Add(new RMA_History
                {

                    Kundenavn = kundenavn,
                    Ordrenummer = ordrenummer


                });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

      }

            return Json(new RMA_History {Kundenavn=kundenavn , Ordrenummer=ordrenummer }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

AJAX:

```
<form id="RMAForm">
<input name="Ordrenummer" id="Ordrenummer" type="text" >

<input name="Kundenavn" id="Kundenavn" type="text" >

<button id="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btn").click(function (e) {


                e.preventDefault();

                var kundenavn = $("#Kundenavn").val();
                var ordrenummer = $("#Ordrenummer").val();


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/Account/ProcessRequestRMA",
                    dataType: 'json',

                    data: {
                        send:"send",
                        kundenavn: kundenavn,
                        ordrenummer: ordrenummer,

                    },

                    success: function (status) {


                        if (!$.trim(status)) {
                            alert("What follows is blank: ");
                        }

                        else {
                            status.Kundenavn = kundenavn;
                            status.Ordrenummer = ordrenummer;
                        }

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                });


            });


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: why have you got `RMA_History model` **and** separate fields for ordernumber etc in your action method parameters? You seem to be trying to catch the same values twice, which makes no sense. That's assuming that RMA_History contains "ordernumber" and "kundenavn" fields already, which from your code it seems that it does.

Comment: Also a good reason you can't see what's going wrong is because your try-catch block catches the exception, assigns its message to a variable which is then not used for anything, and then suppresses the exception. I'm not sure what you think this is meant to achieve? If you want to fail gracefully when the email fails to send, then fine, but at least log the exception properly then you can investigate it. Anyway for now you should set some breakpoints in your C# code to see whether you're getting some exceptions

Comment: alright i will :)

Comment: @ADyson i moved out ModelState.IsValid out of try and catch , and than i tried again when i submit button i get error in console , POST localhost:xxx/Account/ProcessRequestRMA 500 (Internal Server Error) and than i debugged my controller i setbreak point where modelState started,but everything seems fine , modelState is true and its contains data, what would going wrong ! also updated my question

Comment: 500 internal server error means the server definitely crashes somewhere. Set a breakpoint inside your catch block in case it crashes, then you can see the exception value. Also you can step through the code line by line until it fails too

Answer (score 0):

look at this example :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type : "POST",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        //dataType: "json",
        data : { firstDate : monday,
                secondDate : lastday}
                    //student_name : $('#id_student_name').val()
    }).then(function(data) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var a = 0; a < obj.results.length; a++) {
            res[a] = obj.results[a];
            dates.push(obj.results[a].DATESTART);
        }
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: tried,but still no luck :( or if you can give me example or add more details :) thanks.

Comment: try test your controller with a simple asp page dont use ajax

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create a new class for return json.You shouldn't return a entity object to ajax request.

For example:

```
public class RmaHistoryJson
{
    public string Kundenavn { get; set; }
    public string Ordrenummer { get; set; }
}
```

So what is the error details for database insert process?